# JavaScript: Having a hard time diagnosing a bug

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to go through a lesson on some JavaScript, but I am stuck on one particular question:

**This function should create a 2 dimensional array pre-populated with zeros.  The output appears correct, but it has a bug. Explain what's wrong and fix it.**

```js
function defaultMatrix(size) { // returns array
  var defaultValue = 0;
  var row = [];
  var matrix = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    row.push(defaultValue);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    matrix.push(row);
  }
  console.log(matrix);
  return matrix;
}

defaultMatrix(4);
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/o5pbdL4h/19/)

In the snippet, it definitely runs as expected; calling defaultMatrix() will display a 2D matrix full of zeroes in the web console.

What I can't wrap my head around is the "bug" that this code allegedly has. **What is it, and how should I fix it?**

Comment: every row in the matrix references the same array (`row`) - try setting `matrix[0][0] = 1` just before you log it - https://jsfiddle.net/d3em9yr8/

Comment: does this actually create size*size zeros? what happens when you change one value in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the snippet, it definitely runs as expected...

No, it doesn't. :-) You're reusing the **same** array `size` times. You need to create `size` arrays, see `***` comment:

```js
function defaultMatrix(size) { // returns array
  var defaultValue = 0;
  var row = [];
  var matrix = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    row.push(defaultValue);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    matrix.push([...row]); // *** *Copy* the row
  }
  console.log(matrix);
  return matrix;
}

defaultMatrix(4);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you need to support older environments without ES2015+ support, this:

```
matrix.push([...row]); // *** *Copy* the row
```

should be:

```
matrix.push(row.slice()); // *** *Copy* the row
```

Comment: Okay, that helps a lot! This solved my problem and it looks much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```js
function MatrixMaker(rows, cols = null){
  this.matrix = []; this.rows = rows;
  this.cols = cols === null ? rows : cols;
  this.init = ()=>{
    this.matrix.splice(0);
    for(let i=0,a,l=this.rows; i<l; i++){
      a = []; this.matrix.push(a);
      for(let n=0,c=this.cols; n<c; n++){
        a.push(0);
      }
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.init();
}
const mm = new MatrixMaker(4);
console.log(mm.matrix);
```

I haven't added the row and column getters and setters. That should be easy for you.